# Xamarin - Layout cloud not be loaded: The operation failed due to an internal error

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

Error message is: [Layout cloud not be loaded: The operation failed due to an internal error: com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.HardwareConfig.(IILCom/android/resources/Density;FFLcom/android/resources/ScreenSize;Lcom/android/resources/ScreenOrentation;Z)V]

Is in Visual Studio 2015, and the SDK tools version is 24.3.4(the lasted).

I try to removed and installed it again many times, but didn't worked.

In the Xamarin Studio also has the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a know bug, that got resolved with the current update from the stable channel.

Comment: Should I update Xamarin for Visual Studio or other else?

Comment: I update Xamarin for Visual Studio and it worked, thanks